# LINQ results matching ALL relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, contains

I have a many to many relationship as follows:

**Products Table:**

```
ProductID 
Description
```

**ProductFeatures Table:**

```
FeatureID 
ProductID 
FeatureValue
```

Any Product can have many Features.
I have a  Feature class

```
public class Feature
{
    public Guid FeatureID { get; set; }
    public string FeatureValue { get; set; }
}
```

And a list of Features  that come from a search

```
List<Feature> searchFeaturesList = new List<Feature>();

foreach (string var in Request.QueryString)
{
    searchFeaturesList.Add(new Feature { FeatureID = new Guid(var.ToString()),   FeatureValue = Request.QueryString[var] });
}
```

How can I get a list of all products that match ALL the feature IDs AND feature Values on the list using LINQ to SQL. 
I tried using Contains but I get a result of all the products that match ANY of the features. I need it to match ALL the features.
Please note that each FeatureID can have different FeatureValue
Thank you

Comment: Show us your code where you tried using Contains. It's likely just a small change that needs to be applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = Products.AsQueryable();

foreach (var feature in searchFeaturesList)
{
     // create here new values of featureId and featureValue otherwise will get the first ones from the iterator
     var featureId = feature.FeatureID;
     var featureValue = feature.FeatureValue;
     // each feature id and value is tested if exists in the ProductFeatures
     query = query.Where(p=>p.ProductFeatures
                             .Any(pf=> pf.FeatureID == featureId && pf.FeatureValue == featureValue));
}
```

Comment: works great! thank you!

not really sure I understand why you have to create new values of featureId and featureValue. But it certainly doesn't work if you don't do it like you noted.